# What's the recommended way to wrap deeply nested Hashes in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have a Hash, and I need to access the following:

```
parsed["HotelInformationResponse"]["PropertyAmenities"]["PropertyAmenity"]
```

that needs to go on a line with a variable assignment. This makes it longer than 80 characters, which is where I wrap my lines. What's the most elegant way to wrap that to make it fit?

Comment: I guess you could use \ for line continuation... but I personally wouldn't worry about what you have that much. https://gist.github.com/b06ed6712e6ea0a18a5d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text editors are only a tool. Just because you wrap your lines at 80 characters doesn't mean that 100% of lines *should* be under 80 characters. There are expressions which cannot (or should not) be broken down and happen to be long. As a language aiming for syntax which reads like natural language, sometimes verbose method or variable names (such as "HotelInformationResponse") require more space.

To directly answer, you can assign different parts to separate variables:

```
response = parsed["HotelInfomationResponse"]
amenities = response["PropertyAmenities"]
amenity = amenities["PropertyAmenity"]
```

This would be preferable if you are reusing parts of the hash, so you aren't calling `parsed["HotelInformationResponse"]["PropertyAmenities"]` repeatedly.